# What goes in the tx hash preimage when signing with 0x83 (SINGLE|ANYONECANPAY)?

Tags: signature, sighash-flags, bip143

I have script to create a P2WPKH to P2WPKH transaction (1 input, 1 output) and sign it with the sighash type 0x01 SIGHASH_ALL.

Which fields would I need to change in the tx digest preimage to turn the signature into one with a sighash type of 0x83 (SINGLE|ANYONECANPAY)? I'm having trouble understanding the documentation in bip_143.

For reference, the tx digest preimage:

> Double SHA256 of the serialization of:
>        1. nVersion of the transaction (4-byte little endian)
>        2. hashPrevouts (32-byte hash)
>        3. hashSequence (32-byte hash)
>        4. outpoint (32-byte hash + 4-byte little endian) 
>        5. scriptCode of the input (serialized as scripts inside CTxOuts)
>        6. value of the output spent by this input (8-byte little endian)
>        7. nSequence of the input (4-byte little endian)
>        8. hashOutputs (32-byte hash)
>        9. nLocktime of the transaction (4-byte little endian)
>       10. sighash type of the signature (4-byte little endian)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From BIP143:

> If the ANYONECANPAY flag is not set, hashPrevouts is the double SHA256
>   of the serialization of all input outpoints;
>
> Otherwise, hashPrevouts is a uint256 of 0x0000......0000.

All the details you need are in the BIP

Comment: Thanks. It feels like I've tried every combination of setting hashPrevouts, hashSequence, hashOutputs to 0x0000......0000, as well as the sighash type itself, but I keep getting the error message:
error message:
non-mandatory-script-verify-flag (Signature must be zero for failed CHECK(MULTI)SIG operation) (code 64)

Comment: Have you looked at the code? You might find it more helpful: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/script/interpreter.cpp#L1238-L1282 or in bcoin: https://github.com/bcoin-org/bcoin/blob/master/lib/primitives/tx.js#L637-L720

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know cpp so it's a bit hard to follow

Comment: @Darius bcoin is JavaScript, if that helps. What language are you using to compute this sighash?

Comment: I'm not familiar with JavaScript either. I am using the ecsda and hashlib libraries in python. I am creating a script based off this tutorial: https://github.com/zeltsi/segwit_tutorial/tree/master/transactions
In case you were curious this is what the (non-working) script looks like:
https://github.com/DariusParvin/temp/blob/master/P2WPKH_to_P2WPKH_anyonecanpay.py

Comment: Just took a quick look - you may need check that your txid is little-endian...

Comment: thanks a lot. I know everything else is okay because I used it to create a valid sighash_all tx. From that all I did was change the sighash flag to 0x83, set hashPrevouts, hashSequence, hashOutputs to 0s in the digest, but btc core is telling me the signature is invalid.

Comment: glad to say I finally solved it. It was a stupid mistake. When converting from string to hex, I put 32 zeros which of course only corresponded to 16 bytes of zeros. So yes, all the info was clearly in the BIP and it was my bad!